# Upload from Excel doesn't work on created DAC in Acumatica

Tags: c#, excel, acumatica, erp

I had created a new DAC named PaymentSchedule. It was added to Projects screen (PM301000). We want to add Load Records from file button, but it doesn’t work.
My Data Member looks like:

```
[PXImport(typeof(PMProject))]
    public PXSelect<PaymentSchedule, Where<PaymentSchedule.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> paymentSchedule;
```

AllowUpload has been added to a properties.
I have tried with some few fields, created like in existing DAC(PMTask) but it doesn’t help.
Trace shows:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be related to one of the known issues with PXImportAttribute, that was addressed in the latest 6.10.1025 build. Can you please update your local developer Acumatica instance to the latest 6.1 build #6.10.1025 and verify if that makes the NullReferenceException go away?